# Python: Sort list of similar strings based on another string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a string

```
deplete mineral resources , from 123 in x 123 in x 19 ft , on 24 ft t shaped hole
```

and a list of strings

```
['123', '123', '19', '24', 'in', 'in', 'ft', 'ft', 'deplete mineral', 't', 'resources', 'shaped hole']
```

I want to sort this list based on the given string. When I did `sorted(l, key=s.index)`, I am getting the output as:

```
['deplete mineral', 't', 'in', 'in', 'resources', '123', '123', '19', 'ft', 'ft', '24', 'shaped hole']
```

But my desired output is:

```
['deplete mineral', 'resources', '123', 'in' , '123', 'in' , '19', 'ft', '24', 'ft', 't' , 'shaped hole']
```

The list should be sorted exactly as the string given. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using `pandas` tag? I had not found anything regarding `pandas` in your question! Please try to remove it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is a single operation or something that should happen reapeatedly? Are you always comparing to the same string?

Comment: @Kshitiz Sorry, I will change it asap

Comment: @JohanL Yes, it has to be done repeatedly and each time the string and the list of values changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired pattern. It's not technically a sort though - just a regular expression search of the sort string.

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> sort_str = "deplete mineral resources , from 123 in x 123 in x " \
...            "19 ft , on 24 ft t shaped hole"
>>> 
>>> str_list = ['123', '123', '19', '24', 'in', 'in', 'ft', 'ft', 
...             'deplete mineral', 't', 'resources', 'shaped hole']
>>> 
>>> re.findall('|'.join(str_list), sort_str)
['deplete mineral', 'resources', '123', 'in', '123', 'in', '19', 
 'ft', '24', 'ft', 't', 'shaped hole']
>>>
>>>
>>> desired = ['deplete mineral', 'resources', '123', 'in' , '123', 
...            'in' , '19', 'ft', '24', 'ft', 't' , 'shaped hole']
>>> desired == re.findall('|'.join(str_list), sort_str)
True
```

The [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is simple. It's of the form `"alt_1|alt_2|alt_3"`. What that OR-like expression produces is a pattern matcher that scans a string looking for the substrings "alt_1", "alt_2", or "alt_3".

`str_list` is joined together to form this OR-like expression in this simple fashion:

```py
>>> '|'.join(str_list)
'123|123|19|24|in|in|ft|ft|deplete mineral|t|resources|shaped hole'
```

The ordering of the above expression isn't important - they could be in any order.

This string expression is turned into a regular expression internally when passed in as the first parameter to `re.findall()` and used to find all matching substrings in `sort_str` with the following line:

```py
>>> re.findall('|'.join(str_list), sort_str)
```

`re.findall()` scans `sort_str` from beginning to end looking for substrings that are part of `str_list`. Each occurrence is added to the list it returns.

So the substrings matched will be in the same order as the words in `sort_str`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you explain what you have done here? What is the purpose of joining the strings with 'I'?

Comment: Sure.. I'll add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It's more clear now!

Comment: You're welcome =) I hope this satisfies the requirements for the type of sorting operation you need. As I said, it's not technically a sorting operation, but it will match words in the order scanned.

Comment: Yes, maybe arrange is a better word than sort in this scenario. Once again, thank you for the explanation, it satisfies the other cases as well :)